# Nested recursive types

Tags: java, generics

I have the following set of classes:

```
public interface Policy<DSI extends DupStateInfo<DSI>,
                                SD extends ScenarioData<DSI, SD>,
                                   SS extends ScenarioState<SD, SS>
                                              >
{
   SS apply(SS scenarioState);
}

interface DupStateInfo<DSI extends DupStateInfo<DSI>> {
    String getValue();
    DSI withValue(String newValue);
}
interface ScenarioData<DSI extends DupStateInfo<DSI>, SD extends ScenarioData<DSI, SD>> {
    Collection<DSI> getDupStateInfo();
    SD withDupStateInfo(Collection<DSI> dupStateInfo);
}
interface ScenarioState<SD extends ScenarioState<SD, SS>, SS extends ScenarioState<SD, SS>> {
    SD getScenarioData();
    SS withScenarioData(SD newData);
}
```

There are multiple implementations, where the implementations of `DupStateInfo` will have different fields.  Most of the code that uses works at the level of these interface, but it calls some abstract methods, which need the specific implementation classes to get data specific to that implementation.

This fails to compile:

```
error: type argument SD#1 is not within bounds of type-variable SD#2
  where SD#1,DSI,SD#2,SS are type-variables:
    SD#1 extends ScenarioData<DSI,SD#1> declared in interface Policy
    DSI extends DupStateInfo<DSI> declared in interface Policy
    SD#2 extends ScenarioState<SD#2,SS> declared in interface ScenarioState
    SS extends ScenarioState<SD#2,SS> declared in interface ScenarioState
```

If I remove the `SS` parameter on `Policy`, then it compiles, but then I can not use the fully specialized type of `ScenarioData`.

The `with*` methods allow the general code to update objects with new values, without knowing the specific subclass involved.

If it helps, there is only one implementation of ScenarioData and ScenerioState, but there are multiple implementations of Policy and DupStateInfo.

Is there a way to make this work?

I am using Java 8, but might be able to use Java 10 if needed.

*Edit*

@SeanVanGorder pointed out the problem which was a mismatch in the type parameters.  If he wants to post an answer, I'll accept it.  Otherwise, here is what works.

```
public interface Policy<DSI extends DupStateInfo<DSI>,
                        SD extends ScenarioData<DSI, SD>,
                        SS extends ScenarioState<DSI, SD, SS>
                                   >
{
    SS apply(SS ss);
}

interface DupStateInfo<DSI extends DupStateInfo<DSI>> {
    String getValue();
    DSI withValue(String newValue);
}
interface ScenarioData<DSI extends DupStateInfo<DSI>, SD extends ScenarioData<DSI, SD>> {
    DSI getDupStateInfo();
    SD withDupStateInfo(DSI dupStateInfo);
}
interface ScenarioState<DSI extends DupStateInfo<DSI>, SD extends ScenarioData<DSI, SD>, SS extends ScenarioState<DSI, SD, SS>> {
    SD getScenarioData();
    SS withScenarioData(SD newData);
}
```

Comment: Should `SD extends ScenarioState<SD, SS>` be extending `ScenarioData` instead?

Comment: Yes.  That is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SD extends ScenarioState<SD, SS>` should be extending `ScenarioData` instead:

```
interface ScenarioState<DSI extends DupStateInfo<DSI>, SD extends ScenarioData<DSI, SD>, SS extends ScenarioState<DSI, SD, SS>>
```